# Calculate monthly percentage change of daily basis data in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, date

Let's say I have a daily data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2021)
dates = pd.date_range('20130226', periods=90)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(90, 3)), index=dates, columns=list('ABC'))
df
```

Out:

```
             A   B   C
2013-02-26  85  57   0
2013-02-27  94  86  44
2013-02-28  62  91  29
2013-03-01  21  93  24
2013-03-02  12  70  70
        ..  ..  ..
2013-05-22  57  13  81
2013-05-23  43  68  85
2013-05-24  55  50  53
2013-05-25  75  78  66
2013-05-26  70  93   3
```

For column `A` and `B`, I need to calculate their **monthly pct change** on daily basis, for example, the **monthly pct change value** of `A` for `2013-05-26` will be calculated by: A's value in 2013-05-26 divided by the value in 2013-04-26 minus 1.

My idea is like this: create new columns `'A1', 'B1'` by shifting them one month forward, then `df['A_MoM']` will be calculated by `df['A']/df['A_shifted'] - 1`, same logic for column `B`.

Since not all the months share same length of days, so I will use last day's value of last months, ie., to calculate 2013-03-30's pct change will be calculated by: `2013-03-30's value/2013-02-28's value - 1`.

I tried the code below, but it generates a dataframe with all `NaN`s:

```
df[['A1', 'B1']] = df[['A', 'B']].shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1)).resample('D').last().fillna(method=ffill)
df[['A_MoM', 'B_MoM']] = df[['A', 'B']].div(df[['A1', 'B1']], axis=0) - 1
```

Out:

```
             A  A1   B  B1
2013-02-26 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-02-27 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-02-28 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-03-01 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-03-02 NaN NaN NaN NaN
        ..  ..  ..  ..
2013-05-22 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-05-23 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-05-24 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-05-25 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-05-26 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

How could achieve that correctly? Sincere thanks at advance.

**Edit:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(90, 3)), index=dates, columns=['A_values', 'B_values', 'C'])
df.columns

df1 = df.filter(regex='_values$').shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1)).resample('D').last().ffill().add_suffix('_shifted')
df2 = df.filter(regex='_values$').div(df1.to_numpy(), axis=0) - 1
df.join(df2.add_suffix('_MoM'))
```

Out:

```
ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (90, 2): given (93, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is different columns names, solution is converting `df[['A1', 'B1']]` to numpy array:

```
df[['A1', 'B1']] = df[['A', 'B']].shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1)).resample('D').last().ffill()
df[['A_MoM', 'B_MoM']] = df[['A', 'B']].div(df[['A1', 'B1']].to_numpy(), axis=0) - 1
print (df)
             A   B   C    A1    B1      A_MoM     B_MoM
2013-02-26  85  57   0   NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN
2013-02-27  94  86  44   NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN
2013-02-28  62  91  29   NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN
2013-03-01  21  93  24   NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN
2013-03-02  12  70  70   NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN
        ..  ..  ..   ...   ...        ...       ...
2013-05-22  57  13  81  14.0  50.0   3.071429 -0.740000
2013-05-23  43  68  85   2.0  45.0  20.500000  0.511111
2013-05-24  55  50  53  89.0  52.0  -0.382022 -0.038462
2013-05-25  75  78  66  86.0  54.0  -0.127907  0.444444
2013-05-26  70  93   3   4.0  45.0  16.500000  1.066667

[90 rows x 7 columns]
```

Or if possible assign output to `df1`, so columns names are not changed, so possible divide with same columns names, here `A, B` correctly:

```
df1 = df[['A', 'B']].shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1)).resample('D').last().ffill()
df[['A_MoM', 'B_MoM']] = df[['A', 'B']].div(df1, axis=0) - 1
print (df)
             A   B   C      A_MoM     B_MoM
2013-02-26  85  57   0        NaN       NaN
2013-02-27  94  86  44        NaN       NaN
2013-02-28  62  91  29        NaN       NaN
2013-03-01  21  93  24        NaN       NaN
2013-03-02  12  70  70        NaN       NaN
        ..  ..  ..        ...       ...
2013-05-22  57  13  81   3.071429 -0.740000
2013-05-23  43  68  85  20.500000  0.511111
2013-05-24  55  50  53  -0.382022 -0.038462
2013-05-25  75  78  66  -0.127907  0.444444
2013-05-26  70  93   3  16.500000  1.066667

[90 rows x 5 columns]
```

EDIT: After `resample` is changed also datetimeIndex, so added `reindex` for same indices in both `DataFrames`:

```
np.random.seed(2021)

dates = pd.date_range('20130226', periods=90)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(90, 3)), index=dates, columns=['A_values', 'B_values', 'C'])

df1 = df.filter(regex='_values$').shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1)).resample('D').last().ffill()
print (df1.columns)
Index(['A_values', 'B_values'], dtype='object')

df2 = df.filter(regex='_values$').div(df1, axis=0).sub(1).reindex(df.index)

print (df.filter(regex='_values$').columns)
Index(['A_values', 'B_values'], dtype='object')

df = df.join(df2.add_suffix('_MoM'))
print (df)
            A_values  B_values   C  A_values_MoM  B_values_MoM
2013-02-26        85        57   0          NaN          NaN
2013-02-27        94        86  44          NaN          NaN
2013-02-28        62        91  29          NaN          NaN
2013-03-01        21        93  24          NaN          NaN
2013-03-02        12        70  70          NaN          NaN
             ...       ...  ..          ...          ...
2013-05-22        57        13  81     3.071429    -0.740000
2013-05-23        43        68  85    20.500000     0.511111
2013-05-24        55        50  53    -0.382022    -0.038462
2013-05-25        75        78  66    -0.127907     0.444444
2013-05-26        70        93   3    16.500000     1.066667

[90 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question, since my real dataframe has many columns, let's say columns names are `['A_values', 'B_values', 'C']`, so i need to use `df.filter(regex='_values$')` to filter first two columns, then use `df.join()` and `add_prefix('MoM')`, how could I modify your code? Please don't delete the code you've posted, but add more to suit this case.

Comment: @ahbon - I think then `.to_numpy()` should working well.

Comment: It raises an error which I updated in the post, please check, thanks a lot.